How to center Google Map content in the visible area without being blocked by UI elements in Android Auto?
I'm working on an Android Auto app using MapWithContentTemplate to display a Google Map. When I move the camera to center the current location, it ends up being covered by UI overlays, like the "App Information" box, as shown in this screenshot. Current Android Auto View
In my current implementation, I use googleMap.moveCamera() to center the map to current location, but this causes the current location to get blocked by overlays. Here’s the relevant part of my code:
class SurfaceRenderer(
    private val carContext: CarContext,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
) : DefaultLifecycleObserver, ILocationReceiver {

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SurfaceRenderer"
        private const val MSG_RENDER_FRAME = 1
    }

    private var mSurface: Surface? = null
    private var mVisibleArea: Rect? = null
    private var mStableArea: Rect? = null
    private  var googleMap: GoogleMap? = null

    private lateinit var virtualDisplay: VirtualDisplay
    private var presentation: Presentation? = null
    private var isBound = false

    private val mCarContext: CarContext = carContext


    private fun isSurfaceReady(surfaceContainer: SurfaceContainer): Boolean {
        return surfaceContainer.surface != null && surfaceContainer.dpi != 0 && surfaceContainer.height != 0 && surfaceContainer.width != 0
    }

    private val mSurfaceCallback = object : SurfaceCallback {
        override fun onSurfaceAvailable(surfaceContainer: SurfaceContainer) {
            synchronized(this@SurfaceRendererNew) {
                if (!isSurfaceReady(surfaceContainer)) {
                    return
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "Surface available $surfaceContainer")
                mSurface?.release()
                mSurface = surfaceContainer.surface

                virtualDisplay = carContext
                    .getSystemService(DisplayManager::class.java)
                    .createVirtualDisplay(
                        "Map",
                        surfaceContainer.width,
                        surfaceContainer.height,
                        surfaceContainer.dpi,
                        surfaceContainer.surface,
                        DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY
                    )
                presentation = Presentation(carContext, virtualDisplay.display)
                val mapView = MapView(carContext)
                mapView.onCreate(null)
                mapView.onStart()
                mapView.onResume()
                presentation!!.setContentView(mapView)
                presentation!!.show()
                mapView.getMapAsync { google ->
                    googleMap = google

                    googleMap!!.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            carContext,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            carContext,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        googleMap!!.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                    }
                }

                googleMap?.projection?.visibleRegion
                renderFrame()
            }
        }

        override fun onVisibleAreaChanged(visibleArea: Rect) {
            synchronized(this@SurfaceRendererNew) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Visible area changed: $visibleArea")
                mVisibleArea = visibleArea
                renderFrame()
            }
        }

        override fun onStableAreaChanged(stableArea: Rect) {
            synchronized(this@SurfaceRendererNew) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Stable area changed: $stableArea")
                mStableArea = stableArea
                //moveCurrentLocationToStableAreaCenter()
                renderFrame()
            }
        }

        override fun onSurfaceDestroyed(surfaceContainer: SurfaceContainer) {
            synchronized(this@SurfaceRendererNew) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Surface destroyed")
                mSurface?.release()
                mSurface = null
            }
        }
    }

    private val mHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        when (it.what) {
            MSG_RENDER_FRAME -> {
                doRenderFrame(); true}
            else -> {false}
        }
    }

    init {
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SurfaceRenderer created")
        mCarContext.getCarService(AppManager::class.java).setSurfaceCallback(mSurfaceCallback)
    }


    private fun renderFrame() {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_RENDER_FRAME)
    }

    private fun doRenderFrame() {
        if (mSurface == null || mSurface?.isValid == false) return
    }

    override fun locationUpdated(location: Location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Getting current location $location")
        val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude), 15f)
        googleMap?.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)
        //moveCurrentLocationToVisibleAreaCenter(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
    }

    private fun moveCurrentLocationToVisibleAreaCenter(currentLocation: LatLng) {
        val googleMap = googleMap ?: return
        val projection = googleMap.projection

        val currentLocationScreenPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(currentLocation) ?: return
        val visibleAreaCenterX = mVisibleArea?.centerX() ?: return
        val visibleAreaCenterY = mVisibleArea?.centerY() ?: return
        val visibleAreaCenterPoint = Point(visibleAreaCenterX, visibleAreaCenterY)

        val offsetX = visibleAreaCenterPoint.x - currentLocationScreenPoint.x
        val offsetY = visibleAreaCenterPoint.y - currentLocationScreenPoint.y
        val adjustedScreenPoint = Point(
            currentLocationScreenPoint.x + offsetX,
            currentLocationScreenPoint.y + offsetY
        )
        val adjustedLatLng = projection.fromScreenLocation(adjustedScreenPoint)
        adjustedLatLng?.let {
            val cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(it, 10f)
            googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate)
        }
    }
}


I want the map to adjust so that the current location and my map content stays within the visible area, even when there are UI overlays.
So, How can I adjust the camera or map content so that it remains fully visible in the usable area of the map, even when there are UI overlays in Android Auto?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Would it be possible for you provide a sample app using this repo?
